# Normalize Git Curly Brace Formatting (Same Line vs Next Line) Convention on Merge

Tags: git, code-formatting, curly-braces

I am very new to Git (I have been using TFS for about a decade now and have been researching Git for a few days) and am prototyping switching our development team over to using Azure Repos instead of TFS.

**Problem:** A common problem I run into (and one of my least favorite types of problem) are merges when one programmer reformats a code file to have a different curly brace formatting rule (i.e. same line vs next line) than the file had before and the merge logic shows hundreds of changes (one for each curly brace change) and I can't easily tell where the actual logic changes are in the code file when I go to diff or check in the file. I know this should never happen, but some programmers do it anyways.

**Question:** I recently learned that Git can normalize line endings between windows and mac/linux developer systems (the \r\n vs \n problem) with using the crlf setting, and I was wondering if there was some function in Git to normalize code formatting conventions like the curly brace new line vs same line style?

**Desired Solution:** What I would like is for the Git repo to always use one curly brace style (which we will decide on as a team), then when a developer merges code it is automatically formatted into the agreed upon format for the repo, and then when a developer pulls code from a repo it is formatted into the style of their preference so the same-liners and next-liners can live in peace and the ugly merge problem of switching a code file from one formatting convention to another would be forever solved. Is there a way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to use a different tool for this, not git. I know there was a research project for version control to store a syntax tree instead of lines of text, and format the code based on user preference on checkout, like you were asking, but it was abandoned ~15 years ago.

Your team could have a script they invoke before committing (or a git precommit hook?), which runs a code formatter to use the team's preferred format. Then after pulling, any developer would run the code formatter with their own preferred settings. But I don't think they can fix git diffs showing  the team standard.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a git-hook shell script that checks all the files that have been changed and apply mvn prettier to it: https://github.com/HubSpot/prettier-maven-plugin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).